# lists defined-vmethod seems not to work

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

in different occasions i ran into this issue.

I want to test if some value is defined in a list, but the lists vmethod only returns false;

e.g in this case:

```
  lines = "polyline";
  validLineOptions = ['line', 'polyline', 'curved', 'ortho', 'spline'];
  IF validLineOptions.defined(lines);
    GET( "/* using style " _ lines _ "*/\n");
  ELSE;
    GET( "/* using default style */\n");
    lines = '';
  END;
```

this always runs in the `ELSE` clause.

some version info:

```
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 0 (v5.26.0) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int

  Wed May 31 02:57:08 2017: "Module" Template
    *   "installed into: C:\strawberry\perl\vendor\lib"
    *   "LINKTYPE: dynamic"
    *   "VERSION: 2.27"
    *   "EXE_FILES: bin/tpage bin/ttree"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the value of a list element to look it up.

This is what [the documentation](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_List_Virtual_Methods) says about `defined` on *lists* (arrays in TT).

> Returns a true or false value if the item in the list denoted by the
>   argument is defined.
>
> ```
> [% list.defined(3) ? 'yes' : 'no' %]
> ```
>
> When called without any argument, list.defined returns true if the
>   list itself is defined (e.g. the same effect as scalar.defined).

However, this is what you do.

> ```
> lines = "polyline";
> validLineOptions.defined(lines)
> ```

This uses the variable `lines` with a string value as the *index* of the list. The index is supposed to be a number, because we are not dealing with a *hash* (associative array). The values in this list are ordered and numbered. You cannot access them by value.

I think what you are trying to do is to check whether the value exists in the list. There are several ways to do that.

```
validLineOptions.grep(lines)
```

uses `grep` to find the element in the array and checks if the number of returned values is true. If there was no match, it returns false.

However, you can also use a hash as a lookup.

```
lines = "polyline";
validLineOptions = {
    'line'     = 1, 
    'polyline' = 1, 
    'curved'   = 1, 
    'ortho'    = 1, 
    'spline'   = 1
};
IF validLineOptions.exists(lines);
```

This will check if the *key* in the hash *exists*. It's an easy way to check if a value is allowed.

Comment: then it was a misunderstanding of the documentation.
Is there an easy way to transform a list of values into a hash with the list elements as keys?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch yes, a loop, as there's no `map` in TT. Something like `FOREACH key IN [ list ]; hash.$key = 1; END;`

Comment: this is the obvious way (the '[', ']' can be left out - it is already a list, or am I wrong?). i meant some inline way - but does not seems so - but thanks.

Comment: In normal Perl you'd go `my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array` or `my %hash; $hash{$_} = 1 for @array;`. But I don't see that in TT. You could add your own vmethod via your TT object to implement it. Or probably there might be one on CPAN.

Comment: @ikegami fair enough. Cheers.